# AuthLogic changing Rails 3 initialization order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, authlogic

I've got a working Rails 3.1 application with which I'm now trying to use Authlogic. It's being deployed in production under a sub-uri in a reverse-proxy situation. Thus far, I've gotten this to work just fine by setting `ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']` in `config/environments/production.rb`- everything's worked correctly, notably including `javascript_include_tag`, `link_to`, resource routing, and so forth.

Adding Authlogic, however, broke `javascript_include_tag` and `stylesheet_include_tag`- Rails doesn't include `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT` in the generated URL like it had been doing before. Everything else is just fine, however- `url_for`, `form_for`, `new_*_path`, etc. all are working fine. I did some digging, and eventually figured out that the `*_include_tag` functions use a global configuration option called `relative_url_root`, and that this property is set during initialization on line 15 of `actionpack/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb`. I added some debug statements, and saw that without AuthLogic, the order of operations was as follows:

1. `environments/*.rb` loaded
2. `production.rb` evaluated, and `ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']` set
3. The code in `actionpack/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb` run, and ActionController's `relative_url_root` config property set.

If I add `gem authlogic` to the app's Gemfile, however, the order changes- the action_controller metal stuff happens *first*, and then the environment-specific stuff gets run. So, under these conditions, at the time that the `relative_url_root` config parameter is being set, `ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']` *hasn't* yet been set, and so as far as certain parts of the app are concerned it doesn't exist.

Looking through the code for Authlogic, I can't see anything that would affect the Rails initialization stuff- it doesn't seem to be registering any Engines, Initializers, or anything else like that (though I could certainly be wrong about that). The app's Gemfile includes several other gems besides Authlogic, and none of them seem to be affecting the app this way. It doesn't seem to matter what order I put the gems in the Gemfile, which I suppose logically means that it must be something that Authlogic, specifically, is doing- but I sure can't figure out what. Any ideas?